# seems I can reorder a phrase like that and keep the gist, right?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

In the text(wirh is a headline):

"A snowstorm left hundreds stuck overnight on the interstate south of Washington. A United States senator was among those trapped."

Can i rewrite the part: "the interstate south of Washington" as:

south of Washington interstate ?

so that would go like:

"A snowstorm left hundreds stuck overnight in south of Washington interstate. A United States senator was among those trapped."

Comment: As it stands, your rewrite is *syntactically* invalid because ***the** interstate* always requires an article, regardless of whether it's preceded by "south of Washington". But whereas ***...stuck overnight on the south of Washington interstate*** is syntactically valid, it's not very idiomatic, and should be avoided. Note that ***...on the Washington interstate*** is fine, but you can't idiomatically "overload" that adverbial element with ***south of*** in such contexts. I don't know whether "south of Washington" is a "noun adjunct" or "adjective", nor do I know if that's relevant here.

Comment: @FumbleFinger, very good answer

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot reorder it like that.  The interstate is south of Washington, but "south of Washington interstate" is not a natural re-phrasing; it sounds like there is something called "Washington interstate" and the event happened south of that place.

It might help to think of the original statement as "...the interstate *which is* south of Washington".

Comment: I wonder whether the OP is aware that 'the interstate' means a road?

Comment: @Kate Bunting: I was wondering if I could use "interstate" as noun and "south of Washington" as a phrase describing that noun. Hence: south of Washington interstate

Comment: We say '_on_ a road' rather than _in_, and there is no reason to change the word order. It means 'that section of the inter-state road which is south of Washington'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, I get it but let me ask you pease, theoretically: "south of Washington interstate" usage having "interstate" as noun and "south of Washington" as a phrase describling that noun is correct right? even if that is odd right?

Comment: Yes, an adjectival phrase can come before a noun - _a long-expected party_ - but, as FumbleFingers says above, _the south of Washington interstate_ is not very idiomatic

Comment: As Kate points out, when we use an entire phrase as an adjective, we usually use dashes so it looks like one word, like *a yet-to-be-determined course* or *a south-of-Washington* interstate.

Comment: @Kate Bunting thankx a lot

Comment: @stangdon, that helped